# Where to define different asset files for dev/prod mode? - Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I would like to use different js files for development and production mode in Yii2. The development mode has lot of files unminified, although the production would have a single file.

The development asset goes like this:

```
namespace frontend\assets;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class AppAsset extends AssetBundle {
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/main.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/app/_variables.js',
        'js/app.js',
        'js/app/_api_conn.js',
        'js/app/_docCookies.js',
        'js/app/ ..... .js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset',
    ];
}
```

And I would like to have this particular bundle like this in production mode, already merged and minified locally:

```
namespace frontend\assets;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class AppAsset extends AssetBundle {
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/main.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/wfapp_all_min.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset',
    ];
}
```

As the [Yii2 documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#customizing-asset-bundles) explains there is a single method to do this, but I can't find out, where to add it (the example is for jquery asset, but seems right method for my case as well):

```
'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
    'js' => [
        YII_ENV_DEV ? 'jquery.js' : 'jquery.min.js'
    ]
],
```

So what is the proper way to implement this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of different amount of files for debug and production servers, you can set them during initialization in [init()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetbundle.html#init%28%29-detail) method:

```
public function init()
{
    $this->js = !YII_DEBUG ? ['js/wfapp_all_min.js'] : [
        'js/app/_variables.js',
        'js/app.js',
        'js/app/_api_conn.js',
        'js/app/_docCookies.js',
        'js/app/ ..... .js',
    ];

    parent::init();
}
```

Don't forget to call the parent implementation at the end.